# What would happened if jenkins get restarted at the time of execution of jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

Suppose i have set a Jenkins job from 12 pm to 1pm. Let us say job has been started. Now suppose Administrator has set Jenkins to be restarted at 12:30 PM. What would happen- will my script gets paused or gets failed?

Answer (score 0):

Surely your builds will abort if jenkin is going for a restart/shutdown. I have seen some cases where you lose even the build log for that particular build.

(jenkins_url)/safeRestart. This will allow all running builds to complete.

(jenkins_url)/restart will force a restart without waiting for builds to complete.